# Android fcm receive notification from mysql when condition is set

Tags: php, android, mysql, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm currently implement firebase cloud messaging to receive notification from mysql database when a condition in table row data is met. What i currently have right now is just a simple push notification when i enter a php file using browser. Below is all my coding.

**push_notification.php**

```
<?php 

function send_notification ($tokens, $message)
{
    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array(
         'registration_ids' => $tokens,
         'data' => $message
        );

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key = AAAA0********* ',
        'Content-Type: application/json'
        );

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);  
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
   $result = curl_exec($ch);       

   if ($result === FALSE) {
       die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
   }

   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
}

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "fcm");
$sql = " Select fcm_token From fcm_notification";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$tokens = array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $tokens[] = $row["fcm_token"];
    }
}

mysqli_close($conn);
$message = array("message" => " FCM PUSH NOTIFICATION TEST MESSAGE");
$message_status = send_notification($tokens, $message);
echo $message_status;

?>
```

**MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {

    String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

    registerToken(token);
}

private void registerToken(String token) {

    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    RequestBody body = new FormBody.Builder()
            .add("fcm_token", token)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("http://192.168.1.5/fcm/register.php")
            .post(body)
            .build();

    try {
        client.newCall(request).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
}

private void showNotification(String message) {

    Intent i = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("FCM Test")
            .setContentText(message)
            .setLights(Color.BLUE,1,1)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0,builder.build());
}
}
```

**fcm_token table**

[token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAu4T.png)

Right now how do i able to receive a notification from mysql database when a user `balance` is less than `0.5` and this is my `user` table

[user table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWOll.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have set up your system good enough to do the basic thing of sending and receiving the Push Notification.

From what I get is, you are having a system where you want to send a push notification when the user balance is less than 0.5. You can write code in PHP where there is balance manipulation to check user's current balance and send the Push Notification.

OR

You can set up a cron to check balance of each user and send them notification if there balance is less than 0.5

Comment: I have heard about cron job but i don't know how to use it and maybe i don't plan to use it. How do i write code in php? I never done this before, could you show me the first step?